# showing a splash page while uploading an asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, splash-screen

We have a live & deployed ASP.Net application which is quite busy, which takes around 30 - 60 seconds to load when the binary (bin folder) has been uploaded.  Currently, we are performing updates and maintenance on a relatively frequent basis (once or twice a day), as this project has just been launched.

The system is currently using 1 web server, and website is hosted on IIS.  We do not intend to increase the amount of servers for the time being.  Basically, we would like that when the user visit the website, e.g www.website.com, they get a splash page, something like:

```
Website undergoing maintenance and will be back online in a moment
```

We have tried this approach - In IIS, we have defined the default documents in this order (top is first in priority)

```
1. splashPage.html
2. default.aspx
```

Now, when the website is live and OK, we renamed the `splashPage.html` as `splashPage2.html`, so that it is not found by IIS, and reverts to the #2 entry, `default.aspx`.  Before we upload, we rename it back from `splashPage2.html` to `splashPage.html`, so that it finds it and shows it.

The problem is that it seems that IIS treats the web application as a whole - Even though HTML files require no background processing, if the web application is still loading, the  user still has to wait the 30 - 60 seconds until it loads, defeating the purpose of the splash page.

Any ideas how we can overcome this problem, with the current infrastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[App_Offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) will do the trick for you.

Basically, place this file (including your desired markup) in the root of your Application and your users will automatically see the contents until you take it back out.

Comment: My problem is the application load time. The app_offline.htm trick, although good in concept, will shutdown the web app when it is there. Once i rename it, the app is started. This still leaves a 30-60 second without the user knowing whats hapening

Comment: Are you using a pre-compiled site (all bundled into .dlls and you can't view the code-behind)? If not, that may give you a faster start-up. Other than that, there's not a lot you can do - making frequent updates to your site in the manner you describe isn't the best way to do it. Perhaps have an announced "maintenance" period each day, or do it overnight.

Comment: If its an issue maintenance, it has to be done there and then, and cannot wait. Yes i am using a pre-compiled site.

Comment: I think you're going to have to live with it - it sounds like your site would have benefitted form more testing by a smaller userbase to avoid 'maintenance' several times a day.

Answer (score 0):

Is the application

- being compiled on the fly => [precompile it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx)
- loading slowly? profile it

Comment: I am using a web application not a website, thus it is automatically compiled

Comment: Regarding profiling,  that gap is mainly the loading of database items required, and NHibernate initialisation, and there is not much that can be improved.